# npm ELIFECYCLE error exit status 1

Tags: node.js, npm, telegram

So, I've been trying to setup a telegram bot using now but I'm getting the *ELIFECYCLE* error when typing `npm start`. I have both nodejs and npm at their latest version.

The script does work because when I run `node index.js` works just fine, the problem only occurs when I try `npm start` or when I try to deploy it with now.

I'm running this on fedora up to date

So here's the error when I try to run `npm start`

```
[root@localhost my-telegram-bot]# npm start

> telegram-bot@1.0.0 start /home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-bot
> node index.js

events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::430
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
at listen (net.js:1294:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1390:5)
at EventEmitter.listen (/home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-
bot/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-bot/index.js:43:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)

npm ERR! Linux 4.13.5-200.fc26.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! telegram-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the telegram-bot@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the telegram-bot 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs telegram-bot
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls telegram-bot
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-bot/npm-debug.log
```

I included the debug log too:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@3.10.10
3 info using node@v6.11.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~prestart: telegram-bot@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, 
continuing
7 info lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: telegram-bot@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: PATH: 
/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/home/fedora/Scrivania/my-
telegram-bot/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/home/fedora/.local/bin:/home/fedora/bin
10 verbose lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: CWD: /home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-bot
11 silly lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'node index.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle telegram-bot@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: telegram-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/lifecycle.js:255:16)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> 
(/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:230:5)
15 verbose pkgid telegram-bot@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /home/fedora/Scrivania/my-telegram-bot
17 error Linux 4.13.5-200.fc26.x86_64
18 error argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v6.11.3
20 error npm  v3.10.10
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error telegram-bot@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the telegram-bot@1.0.0 start script 'node index.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the telegram-bot package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     node index.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project 
with:
23 error     npm bugs telegram-bot
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls telegram-bot
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "telegram-bot",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
  "start" : "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "------ <------@gmail.com>",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: The error is obvious and clear in the log.

Answer (score 2):

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::430 
This points to me that you are already using the port that telegram bot is trying to listen to. Try changing the port that telegram bot uses. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was that I had a `node_modules` folder in a **parent folder** e.g.: `(node_mudules used to be here)../../my-app`.

By deleting the folder the issue was resolved.