# Npm doesn't work There is no problem with my NPM. (This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

Hello I can't start my Vue project.

I can run my vue project on my laptop but when I try to run on my dekstop it doesn't work.

I got a error. This is the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'serve'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.13.4
3 info using node@v12.16.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'preserve', 'serve', 'postserve' ]
5 info lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~preserve: vuefire@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: vuefire@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\stageFinder\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\flutter\bin;"C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Windows\System32;";C:\Users\Mustafa Bolat\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: CWD: C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\stageFinder
10 silly lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vue-cli-service serve --open' ]
11 silly lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle vuefire@0.1.0~serve: Failed to exec serve script
13 verbose stack Error: vuefire@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve --open`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
14 verbose pkgid vuefire@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\xampp\htdocs\GitHub\stageFinder
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "serve"
18 verbose node v12.16.1
19 verbose npm  v6.13.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error vuefire@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve --open`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the vuefire@0.1.0 serve script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I uninstall the Node js and installed but that doesn't work.

I deleted the project and downloaded it from Github but that also doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ELIFECYCLE error exit status 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756406/npm-elifecycle-error-exit-status-1)

Comment: No it is not helping.