# How to resolve the error "ERR! code ELIFECYCLE"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I am using the Jest to perform the unit testing.

```
"jest": "^26.4.2",
"jest-preset-angular": "^8.3.1"
```

All the test has been passed and ran but got an error as below

```
Test Suites: 20 passed, 20 total
Tests:       26 passed, 26 total
Snapshots:   2 obsolete, 5 passed, 5 total
Time:        92.961 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! idp@0.0.0 test:app: `jest --config ./jest.app.config.js --no-cache`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the idp@0.0.0 test:app script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2020-09-15T09_19_42_790Z-debug.log
```

I tried the below command from the google search, however, it is not working

```
npm cache clean --force

rm -rf node_modules

npm install
```

### error from logs

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'run', 'test:app' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v14.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pretest:app', 'test:app', 'posttest:app' ]
5 info lifecycle idp@0.0.0~pretest:app: idp@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: idp@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: PATH: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/opt/helm@2/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Xamarin Workbooks.app/Contents/SharedSupport/path-bin
9 verbose lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: CWD: /Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp
10 silly lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: Args: [ '-c', 'jest --config ./jest.app.config.js --no-cache' ]
11 silly lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle idp@0.0.0~test:app: Failed to exec test:app script
13 verbose stack Error: idp@0.0.0 test:app: `jest --config ./jest.app.config.js --no-cache`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid idp@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /Users/macbook/Projects/Playtime Projects/IDP/Idp.Bx.Ui/idp
16 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
17 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "test:app"
18 verbose node v14.5.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error idp@0.0.0 test:app: `jest --config ./jest.app.config.js --no-cache`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the idp@0.0.0 test:app script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: check what logs are present in /Users/macbook/.npm/_logs/2020-09-15T09_19_42_790Z-debug.log

Comment: Is this the whole output?
Usually there's a better error message above your test summary.
`npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

Comment: @Helvetios - added logs from the file

Comment: @SanJaisy Could you include the whole console output as well, not just eh debug log?
As you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46756406/npm-elifecycle-error-exit-status-1 there's probably a better error message in the console above the test summary

Comment: @Helvetios  How can I do that, I am not sure how can I achieve that as you have mention

Comment: @SanJaisy delete node_modules folder. run "npm install" in console then run your test script in console and copy paste the console output

Comment: @Helvetios That is the one at the top, that is from the console

Answer (score 1):

```
Snapshots: 2 obsolete, 5 passed, 5 total
```

obsolete - are the cause of the error, after their removal, the error is gone.

Delete the snapshots and rerun the test everything should work fine

Reference - https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9324

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar issue in wdio cucumber setup with node 14, and npm 6. The tests were executed correctly but this error surfaced in every run.

```
error code ELIFECYCLE 
error Exit status 1
```

upgraded to the latest node 16.17.0 and npm 8.18 -- error gone.
The error could be due to non compatible packages

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this problem with this way:

```
rm -rf node_modules && rm ./package-lock.json && npm install
```

After that restart your machine and its working perfectly.

Comment: @SanJaisy try `sudo killall node`. After perform all action which I mentioned.